# How to download inbox and sent item onto outlook for backup

Tags: outlook, webmail

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question., if not please point me in the direction.
I have business email services running with BigRock, which I don't want to continue.

I'd like to take a back up of all the folders on webmail. As I spoke to technical support they said it's not possible. I am able to download inbox but not the rest of it.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

> You'll need access to their IMAP server thru Outlook for this (you need to ask them to help you setup your account on Outlook.
>
> Them Create an Outlook Data File (.pst) to save your information:

Follow this instructions: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/video-create-and-use-personal-folders-outlook-data-files-cc784f7c-70c4-495d-bcbf-f3fcb679651f

> After this, select e-mails from your IMAP account and move to a private folder.
>
> You can export IMAP account too, but for me, i think is better doing manually because i already lost items doing automatically, so, i recommend always do like this. And, it's normal Outlook freezing and stop responding when moving itens from IMAP, don't close.

Another alternative, you can use Mailstore for that (https://www.mailstore.com/). Works great and keep archiving your mail.

Comment: I am copying from IMAP sent item folder and moving it to POP's sent item, that should do it , right ?

Comment: As gicapp mentioned, access Outlook with IMAP account, then save your mailbox as .pst file. POP3 account is ok, but this protocol allows the email client to download the mail on the server, but the client's operations (such as moving items, mark as read, etc.) will not sync with the mail server. It's better using an IMAP account.

Comment: @mark I think you mean POP as another box. You need to move using IMAP, then folder Sent or Sent Items to the personal folder Sent.